# how to sort by many to many field in django query

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class CompanyGroup(models.Model):  
name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)   

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True) 
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(CompanyGroup, related_name='groups', blank=True)
```

I want to show the latest companies added to the group.  I do so with the following:

```
companies = Company.objects.filter(
        groups__name=group_name
        ).order_by('-groups__id')
```

When I print the sql it is ordering by the company_group_id instead of the id of companies_company_groups:

```
ORDER BY `companies_company_groups`.`companygroup_id` ASC
```

I want it to order by:

```
ORDER BY `companies_company_groups`.`id` ASC
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the through model like this.

```
Company.groups.through.objects.all().order_by('-id')
```

This will query the table generated by the many to many relation. Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no "through" variable and I get a syntax error.  Are you sure about this?

Comment: Yes, I use it on django 1.11 from django docs "If you don’t specify an explicit through model, there is still an implicit through model class you can use to directly access the table created to hold the association. It has three fields to link the models." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: I've created small project on github take a look. https://github.com/ocobacho/django_through_example